# How to resolve : Necessitas error: The package appears to be corrupt

Tags: android, qt, android-sdk-2.3, qt-necessitas

I’ve created an andriod application with qt and is successfully running on android version 4.0.4

But when I try to install same apk on device with android version 4.0.3 I get the error message “Application not Installed. The package appears corrupted.”

My application needs permissions to
1. storage
2. network communication

Permissions “android.permissions.INTERNET” & “android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” are given in AndroidManifest.xml

Minimum required SDK: API 9: Android 2.3, 2.3.1, 2.3.2
Target SDK: API 15 : Android 4.0.3, 4.0.4 is set also set.

Can someone tell where I am wrong?

Comment: Why are you not using Qt Android proper? Are you still stuck with Qt 4 for any unmanageable reason?

Comment: I am using Qt Creator 3.0.1 & Qt 5.2.1.  I told I run the application on android version 4.0.4 & 4.0.3

Comment: Is a previous version of the app already installed and you are installing an update? If so, ensure the new APK versionCode value is greater than the existing APK's.